# How we get_post_meta without post id

Tags: post-meta

I want to get my all `posts-meta`, But on the base of `key`. For example the main query for getting the post-meta is

```
 <?php $meta_values = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single); ?>
```

Now i want to get this `post-meta` on the base of `key` only. My current query to get the post-meta is

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_tags'.$userID, true); ?>
```

And i want to remove `$post->ID` from this query is there any way to get this. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

`$post->ID` is what makes the meta value distinguished across all posts with the same meta key.

So if you want to shorthand the  `get_post_meta` call for the current post you can do this:

```
function get_cuurent_post_meta($key){
    global $post;
    return get_post_meta($post->ID,$key,true);
}
```

and you can call it like this:

```
echo get_cuurent_post_meta('custom_tags'.$userID);
```

Now if its not the current post but any post you can do this:

```
function get_meta_value_by_key($meta_key,$limit = 1){
    global $wpdb;
    if (1 == $limit)
        return $value = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s LIMIT 1" , $meta_key) );
    else
        return $value = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s LIMIT %d" , $meta_key,$limit) );
}
```

to get the first meta value of this key just call it like this:

```
echo get_meta_value_by_key('custom_tags'.$userID);
```

and to get all meta values of this key use the `$limit` param ex:

```
$post_meta_array = get_meta_value_by_key('custom_tags'.$userID, 999);
```

Comment: There is one thing i just have to ask is. when i `echo` the `$post_meta_array` it show Array. And when i use `print_r($post_meta_array)` it show me data something like this `Array ( 
 [0] => stdClass Object ( [meta_value] => $custom_tags ) 
 [1] => stdClass Object ( [meta_value] => tag2,tag3,tag4 ) 
 [2] => stdClass Object ( [meta_value] => garlic,soupe )  
 ) ;`. How can i show them in one line with now objects.

Comment: You can chage the output of [get_results ](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results) and then when you have an array you can use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can query your `postmeta` table directly using something like:

```
global $wpdb;

$metas = $wpdb->get_results( 
  $wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta where meta_key = %s", 'add_your_key_here')
 );

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $metas );
echo '</pre>';
```

- [Implementation of custom
  fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields#Implementation_Details)
- [postmeta table](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_postmeta)
- [WPDB Class reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

**UPDATE**
After you get your `$metas`, you pass them in a loop to display the values:

```
if( count($metas) > 0 ){ #check if we got any results
  foreach ($metas as $meta){
    echo $meta->meta_value . "<br />";
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is same as i commet above. Here is my comment.
There is one thing i just have to ask is. when i use `print_r($metas)` it show me data something like this `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [meta_value] => $custom_tags ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [meta_value] => tag2,tag3,tag4 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [meta_value] => garlic,soupe ) ) ;`. How can i show them in one line with now objects.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: @RRikesh Please take a look at `$wpdb->prepare()`. Always prepare your statements, no matter what.

Comment: @kaiser Thanks, I updated my answer. BTW, should I prepare even if I'm hard-coding the value?

Comment: Basically it's a `sprintf()` replacement that cares about replacing `%s` and `%d`. So I'd do it anyway. Even if it's just for other people reading my code or preparing it in case I later move to a dynamic var. To answer your question: No, not in a private case ;)

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, I'll stick to the `prepare` method! :)